# How to access apex select option's selected values without interacting with controller?

Tags: visualforce

I have a page. I have created a select option on page and trying to access selected on same page. I don't have any controller for my page. Is it possible to access selected field values without using any controller and getter/setter.

Comment: You can add JavaScript to the page that can access the values.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the selected value?

Comment: I have to create a dynamic filter for report on VF  page, same as dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

Should be quite easy as mentioned by others in comments. Just to get started, here is little piece of JavaScript:

> **JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getSelectedValue() {

      var selected;
      var options = document.getElementsByName('chooseColor')[0];
      for(option in options){
         console.log('item selected: ' + options[option].selected);
         if(options[option].selected === true){
            selected = options[option].value;
            alert(selected);
         }
      }
  }
```

**Sample Options**

```
<select id="chooseColor" name="chooseColor" size="1" onclick="getSelectedValue()">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="blue" selected="selected">Blue</option>
</select>
```